# How can I match a specific term 1-N times in a regex pattern?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to do matches for a small table of terms that can occur from 1 (generally) to several times and extract each of the terms. Rather than make a complex regex that matches each possibile # of matches I thought there might be a way to do so with regex:

Test data:

```
offices in NY
offices in NY and CA
offices in NY, CA and NJ
offices in NY, CA, and NJ
offices in NY and CA and NJ
offices in NY/CA/NJ
offices in NY, CA, NJ, DE
```

Regex I've tried:

```
/offices in (?<ST>(NY|CA|NJ|DE))/
```

http://regex101.com/r/kL2tD8/1

Comment: If N is unbounded `x{10,}`. Otherwise N must be encoded directly `x{10,20}` (eg. N = 20). Thus, `x` is equivalent to `x{1}`, `x*` is equivalent to `x{0,}` and `x+` is equivalent to `x{1,}`.

Comment: Not that such really helps in this case, which is more about dealing with the various join forms.

Comment: You mean something like this? http://regex101.com/r/zB2oI6/1

Comment: @hwnd I mean something exactly like that thank you. Again I could only mark you up vs marking your reply as the answer.

Comment: @hwnd I have my coder call these using php. I notice you added modifiers (gm). Can he use/implemen those modifiers in that php call as well?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like hwnd got the answer:

```
(?:offices in|\G(?<!^)(?:(?!NY|CA|NJ|DE).)*) *(?<ST>(?:NY|CA|NJ|DE))
```

Comment: yes that worked, I could only mark him up vs marking as the answer because it was a comment as far as I know so I did that.